# How to deal with aborted uploads in Angular?

Tags: angular, http

I can upload files to my backend via a POST request and **it returns an Http 400 Status code when the file is too big. It works perfectly when using Postman.**

When I do this call in a browser (chrome), I get this error:

> zone.js:2933 POST http://localhost:8080/backend/rest/upload/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED

As a results, my **HttpErrorResponse has a status code of 0**:

> HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22277590/what-is-the-likely-cause-of-a-neterr-connection-aborted-when-uploading-a-file) answer explains the problem, **but how to I deal with this problem in Angular ?** I was counting on the returned error message contained in my Http 400 response...

Comment: Just like @Miam84 said bellow this is not an Angular issue. You can check file limit. But can you give more details about your server ? I think you must handle that issue on server side ! Changing some configs I think.

Comment: It is only a problem when uploading files from a browser. As I wrote, using a separate rest client (Postman), I get a 400 as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's more a problem related to your API than to Angular itself... Your API should handle that and return an appropriate 400 error.

As a workaround, and to improve your UI, you can make an angular validation on the file **before** posting it to the backend. If it's too big, then just block the post and notify the user.

You can access the size attribute of the file like this :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <input type="file" (change)="onChange($event)"/>
    </div>
  `,
  providers: [ UploadService ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  onChange(event) {
    var files = event.srcElement.files;
    console.log(files[0].size);
  }
}
```

Comment: That's the easy solution :-) I was looking for a way to prevent the connection to be aborted.